# Приведение типа внутри QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Возможно заголовок выглядит несколько не понятно, поэтому перейду сразу к примеру:

```
double d = 3.14;
QVariant v(d);
qDebug() << v.value<int>();  //3
```

`QVariant` выполнил приведение типа `double` -> `int`.

Я хочу провернуть то же самое, но с указателями:

```
class Foo : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo*)
static const int __idFoo = qRgisterMetaType<Foo*>("Foo*");

//...

Foo *foo = new Foo();
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(foo);
qDebug() << v.value<QObject*>();  //QObject(0x0)
```

Приведение типа не произошло.
**Вопрос:** Можно ли каким-нибудь образом поместить в `QVariant` указатель на объект производного класса, а извлечь указатель на объект базового класса?

**UPD:** Код почти такой же как и мой:

```
class IRow : public QObject{
//...
};

class FirstRow : public IRow{
//...
};

class SecondRow : public IRow{
    FirstRow *_first
    Q_PROPERTY(FirstRow* first READ first WRITE setFirst)
public:
    FirstRow* first() const{
        return _first;
    }
    void first(FirstRow *first){
        _first = first;
    }
//...
};
```

Где-то в другом месте есть функция, которая ничего не знает о конкретных реализациях интерфейса `IRow`. Она должна прочитать все доступные свойства, того объекта который к ней пришел в виде `QVariant`(по-другому никак, там работа с моделями идет), и привести полученное значение к типу интерфейса(`IRow`). И вот оно не приводится. В Qt5 должно, а в Qt4 - никак. Если воспользоваться решением @ixSci то класс `SecondRow` примет вид:

```
class SecondRow : public IRow{
    FirstRow *_first
    Q_PROPERTY(FirstRow* first READ _first WRITE _setFirst)
public:
    FirstRow* first() const{
        return _first;
    }
    void first(FirstRow *first){
        _first = first;
    }
private:
    IRow* _first() const{
        return first();
    }
    void _setFirst(IRow *first){
        _setFirst(qobject_cast<FirstRow*>(first));
    }
//...
};
```

Оно работает, но количество сеттеров и геттеров удвоилось

Comment: `Q_DECLARE` и `qRegister` не должен быть нужен в этом случае. В остальном, странно, что не работает. У меня нет 4.8, чтобы проверить, но в 5 версии всё работает как надо.

Comment: @ixSci, возможно эта фича появилась в Qt5 [QVariant::value() Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value), [QVariant::value() Qt4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#value)

Comment: Почему не устраивает вариант преобразования уже возвращённого значения из `value`?

Comment: @ixSci, `v.value<void*>()` возвращает `0`. Если написать `v.value<Foo*>()`, то вернется тот указатель, который я туда помещал.

Comment: @alexolut, потому что тот класс, который получает `value` ничего не знает о конкретных классах. Ему известен только базовый класс(интерфейс). А я никак не могу достать содержимое `value`, если не знаю реальный тип этого содержимого

Comment: А что возвращает `v.CanConvert<QObject*>()`?

Comment: @alexolut, `false`

Comment: Может быть нужно `QObject` в `QVariant` помещать именно как `QObject`, а не как производный тип? Например: `QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<QObject*>(foo));`. Тогда, возможно, извлечение в `QObject` пройдёт успешно. Пробовали?

Comment: @alexis031182, так оно работает. Но я-то хочу помещать производный, а извлекать базовый :) Как мы уже выяснили в Qt5 так можно.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, так у `QObject`, если я правильно понимаю для чего Вам это всё нужно, имеется метод `metaObject()`, который вернёт `QMetaObject` и из которого можно получить информацию о реальном типе объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При тех данных, что Вы имеете, видимо, самый простой(если не единственный) вариант будет такой

```
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<void*>(foo));
qDebug() << static_cast<QObject*>(v.value<void*>());
```

Можно для этого написать функции-обёртки, которые уменьшат количество кода. Что-нибудь такое:

```
QVariant ptrToQVariant(void* ptr)
{
    return QVariant::fromValue(ptr);
}

QObject* variantPtrToQObject(const QVariant& v)
{
    return static_cast<QObject*>(v.value<void*>());
}
```

и потом:

```
QVariant v = ptrToQVariant(foo);
qDebug() << variantPtrToQObject(v);
```

Comment: Да, я уже тоже пришел к этому варианту. Дело в том, что `QVariuant` я использую в контексте работы со свойствами. Для того чтобы реализовать это решение, придется в каждом классе писать по две пары геттеров и сеттеров. Одни работают с нормальными типами, а другие с `void*`. Если лучшего решения не найдется, придется делать именно так

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, а можете привести пример свойства? Я что-то не могу понять зачем Вам 2 геттера. Ведь решение с `void` почти ничем не отличается от исходного варианта, о котором Вы спрашивали.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, к сожалению, по тому, что Вы привели всё равно ничего не ясно. Там нет `QVariant` и, честно говоря, я совершенно не понял второго Вашего варианта. Не могли бы Вы сделать минимальный пример, который можно собрать и который бы отражал весь путь того, что Вы пытаетесь сохранить и загрузить. В противном случае помочь чем либо Вам будет довольно сложно.

Comment: [Вот компилируемый пример](http://pastebin.com/sC4YtnPH). `QVariant` появляется когда я читаю значения свойства.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, ну так же можно из варианта получить `QObject`, а затем через тот же `qobject_cast<T>()` сконвертировать в нужный класс.

Comment: @alexis031182, в то-то и дело, что нельзя. Из варианта можно получить только то, что в него положил. Во всяком случае, у меня никак иначе не выходит.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, но у Вас в примере все классы наследуются от `QObject`, значит он самый что ни на есть базовый. Тогда почему бы и не класть в вариант именно `QObject`, тем более, что Вы ранее на мой вопрос сказали, что код `QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<QObject*>(foo));` работоспособен и может вернуть `QObject`.

Comment: @alexis031182, похожее решение предложил ixSci, только вместо `QObject*` `void*`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, да, это так. Просто иначе это не решить, если сам вариант в 4-ой версии не тянет требуемый каст. Тут наверное разве что свой аналог варианта писать.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот этот код отлично работает на Qt5

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(){}
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass *someVal = new MyClass();

    QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(someVal);

    qDebug() << var.value<QObject*>(); //MyClass(0x4bea78)

    return 0;
}
```

Если по какой-то причине возвращает 0. Попробуйте зарегистрировать конвертер в метасистеме. Для этого можно воспользоваться вот этой шаблонной функцией:

```
template<class T>
void registerToQObjectConverter()
{
    if(!QMetaType::hasRegisteredConverterFunction<T*, QObject*>())
    {
        QMetaType::registerConverter<T*, QObject*>([](T *_value) -> QObject*
        {
            return _value;
        });
    }
}
```

И в самом начале программы добавить функцию:

```
registerToQObjectConverter<MyClass>();
```

Для всех типов, которые будете хранить в QVariant

Comment: Но вопрос-то по qt4.

Comment: Конвертеры тоже были добавлены в 5-й версии.